# Make an object available when bootstrapping an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When bootstrapping an AngularJS app is it possible to configure the root scope object before any directive in the application is instantiated?

I want to supply an object an make it available to the application via the root scope (or even the injector).

```
var myObject = { /* stuff */ };
// Can I make `myObject` available to the application via AngularJS?
angular.bootstrap(rootDomNode, [APPLICATION_NAME]);
```

Or should I bypass AngularJS for this and stick it in some shared object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the module's .run() function to do that:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
   .run(function($rootscope) { // instance-injector
      // Modify your rootscope here
   });
```